# проблема с функциями в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Первая функция работает, а вторая нет
В английском плохо шарю, поэтому не кидайте ссылки на документацию
Может кто-нибудь разбирается в этой библиотечке

```
from weatherNow import weatherNow
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weather_Now(message):
    if message.text == "Погода сейчас":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, weatherNow)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def change_city(message1):
    message = message1.text
    if "сменить город на" in message:
        msg1 = message.replace("сменить город на ", '')
        if 'у' in msg1:
          msg = msg1.replace('у', 'а')
        else:
          msg = msg1
        with open("conf.py", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as file:
                  file.write('msg ' + '= ' + '"' + msg + '"')
        bot.send_message(message1.from_user.id, f"Меняю город по умолчанию на {msg1}") 
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!

Comment: Рекомендую вторую функцию тоже переделать, т.к. при добавлении новых команд они тоже не будут работать

Comment: не, почему-то теперь не работают обе функции

Comment: В консоли появляются какие-то ошибки?

Comment: нет, не появляются

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос весь код, вместе с импортами

Comment: код состоит из нескольких файлов

Comment: а в основном это и есть весь код кроме `import telebot`

Comment: Попробуйте перезапустить `.py` файл и заново написать первую команду

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: Также соблюдайте регистры букв, если команда начинается с заглавной буквы, то и пишите с заглавной

Comment: да-да, я так и делаю

Comment: Попробуйте удалить `content_types=['text']` в обоих хэндлерах

Comment: сделал, все равно не работает
А декораторы могут быть без аргументов?

Comment: Могут, в таком случае в первый декоратор будут попадать все сообщения, но до второго ничего не дойдет

Comment: Попробуйте обе функции поместить под один хэндлер

Comment: да,  работает только первая

Answer (score 0):

Замените строки

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weather_Now(message):
    if message.text == "Погода сейчас":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, weatherNow)
```

На:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'], text="Погода сейчас")
def weather_Now(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, weatherNow)
```